# NullPointerException using Array of Custom Views

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I decided to optimize my code using a simple loop instead of hardcode, because previously I implemented each PickView separately and it worked fine.

Here is a problematic place:

```
pick = new PickView[9];
int id;
for(int i = 0; i < pick.length; i++) {
    id = getResources().getIdentifier("pick_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    pick[i] = (PickView)findViewById(id);
    pick[i].setOnTouchListener(this); //this is MainActivity, line:54
}
```

...in which unexpectedly I recieved a NullPointerException:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.***}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.***.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    ... 11 more
```

I enclose a PickView class:

```
public class PickView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String text;

    public PickView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PickView);
        text = a.getString(R.styleable.PickView_text);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_view, this);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pick_text);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pick_bg);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void activate(boolean isActive) {
        if (isActive)
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pick_active);
        else
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pick);
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: `(PickView)findViewById(id);` return null ... why ? i'dont know ... show us more code ... maybe you call it before `setContentView` ...

Comment: You havn't initialized your array pick, try this first as in java, arrays must be initialized after declaration.

Comment: @engineer iteresting ... so what this line do: `pick = new PickView[9];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small question do you have a pick_0 resource?

And anyway you should check that you are actually getting an id and that the PickView returned isn't null?

Comment: You made my day! I had ids from "pick_1" to "pick_9". What a simple mistake... Thanks a lot! Stackoverflow rocks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Java doc of `getIdentifier` suggests that it return `0` if not found that is the cause of your problem. So `findViewById` returns `null` if not found.

`public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)`

> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.
>
> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

`int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)`

Comment: Yes `findViewById ` returns null if not found.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find it that way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pick.length; i++)
{
  resources = getResources();
  if(resources == null)
  {
    System.out.println("oops.. no resources");
    throw new RuntimeException("oops... no resources");
  }
  id = resources.getIdentifier("pick_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
  pickView = (PickView) findViewById(id);
  if(resources == null)
  {
    System.out.println("oops.. noo pickView");
    throw new RuntimeException("oops... no pickView");
  }
  pick[i] = pickView;
  pick[i].setOnTouchListener(this); //this is MainActivity, line:54
}
```

Comment: It would be much, safer. ;) Next time I will write sth like this. Problem is solved by Raanan.